# iOS TumblrSDK post photo issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, tumblr

I working on a native iOS application where I need to post to Tumblr.

I found the official TumblrSDK (https://github.com/tumblr/TMTumblrSDK) and decided to use it.

Now that I am testing this SDK, I have run into an issue where I can post a photo to Tumblr from my simulator (using the postPhotoExample project), but executing the EXACT same code from my real iOS device returns an error code (400 - bad request - error uploading photo)

Im running following code from the TumblrSDK example project (postPhoto)

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"blue" ofType:@"png"];
[[TMAPIClient sharedInstance] photo:@"blogName"
                      filePathArray:@[filePath]
                   contentTypeArray:@[@"image/png"]
                      fileNameArray:@[@"blue.png"]
                         parameters:@{@"caption" : @"Test"}
                           callback:^(id response, NSError *error) {
                               if (error)
                                   NSLog(@"Error posting to Tumblr");
                               else
                                   NSLog(@"Posted to Tumblr");
                           }];
```

I am aware that an iOS device is case sensitive and the simulator is not, but the request i send looks exactly the same on each post i send.

Anyone experienced similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this before your code?

```
  // Authenticate via OAuth
[TMAPIClient sharedInstance].OAuthConsumerKey = @"your key";
[TMAPIClient sharedInstance].OAuthConsumerSecret = @"your secret";
[TMAPIClient sharedInstance].OAuthToken = @"your token";
[TMAPIClient sharedInstance].OAuthTokenSecret = @"your token secret";
```

If NOT, go [here](https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/register) and register your Tumblr app, and after that you will get all the keys that you need. Just copy paste them into upper part of code and place thet in your app before code for posting photo.Hope I helped.